# Phonegap disable x-frame-option in webview

Tags: android, cordova, webview

i have a problem that is when i open a site like facebook.com in iframe in my phonegap app don't open because x-frame-option.

my question is can i disable checking x-frame-option from java code of cordova webview ?

or use another webview in the same activity one it top and on at down and change the url of webview ?

i'm not good on phonegap and not good in android please help me :D

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the great solution in this amazing plugin

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizViewManager

you can add a webview to android and ios and select it position it's really great.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it isn't possible to allow it on Cordova because it is up to web view of device to handle. What you probably could do is to first download the HTML for some page with AJAX query, strip the

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="DENY" />
```

of from there and then inject the whole content into iframe. Of course this only works for single page but if that is SPA (single-page application), it might even be enough.

Comment: Thanks sanfor سنفوور :-D but I don't like this way to solve it I decide to make anther webview and create a phone gap plugin to change the URL of the second web view ;) . and if that doesn't work I will use you method and add a basic URL to the HTML of the page to work well. Thank your very much :-)

Comment: @Moh97: You are of course free to implement it what ever way you wish, but since Stack Overflow is Q&A site, it is generally a good practice to mark something as an [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so you could either accept my answer, or then write your own answer describing what you implemented and accept that. This way the information on how to solve problem like this is available for future reference.

Comment: As an additional comment, according to the standard, this HTTP attribute should be ignored when found through a meta tag; the browser should only take its advise when receiving it properly through the HTTP request itself.

This means that if browsers follow the standard, this solution wouldn't affect the outcome.